# How can i shift a 2d array by an 1d array in numpy? The same for 3d by 2d

Tags: python, numpy

Say i have an 2d array and an 1d array like this:

```
a= np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
b= np.array([0,2,1,0])
```

And as a result i want this:

```
out= np.array([[1,2,3,1],[2,3,1,2],[3,1,2,3]])
```

Every values in a is shifted along an axis by a value in an other array.

Is there something like this in numpy or any other common library?
I need to do this for a big array in 3d ( ~ 10000,10000,100) so doing it by iterating feels wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done using advanced indexing. Also you dont need any loops.

```
# Get the row and col indices of the ndarray
rowidx, colidx = np.ogrid[:a.shape[0], :a.shape[1]]
# update row idices
updt_rowidx = rowidx - b
# Use the updated indices
a[updt_rowidx, colidx]
>> array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a function in NumPy called np.roll() that can be used to achieve the desired result. Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]])
b = np.array([0,2,1,0])

out = np.empty_like(a)

for i, shift in enumerate(b):
    out[i] = np.roll(a[i], shift)

print(out)
```